# finding WP sources in a footer file

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, footer

Hoping someone can help. I am trying to edit my footer for a theme but can not figure out where to do so. Its not in the usual appearance, or the customize or even the code. I can not find where it is pulling the configuration for the footer's text. my footer.php file looks like this with a lot of "do action xyz but those template parts do not exist. Where is it getting this from?

I have searched for the do_action yummy_footer_start and just footer and found nothing using windows search to look through all the folders and files as well as the contents.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Theme Palace
 * @subpackage Yummy
 * @since Yummy 0.1
 */

/**
 * yummy_content_end_action hook
 * @hooked yummy_content_end -  10
 *
 */
do_action( 'yummy_content_end_action' );

/**
 * yummy_footer_start hook
 *
 * @hooked yummy_footer_start -  10
 *
 */
do_action( 'yummy_footer_start' );

/**
 * yummy_footer hook
 *
 * @hooked yummy_footer_bottom_start - 11
 * @hooked yummy_footer_social_menu - 15
 * @hooked yummy_copyright -  20
 * @hooked yummy_footer_bottom_end - 25
 *
 */
do_action( 'yummy_footer' );

/**
 * yummy_footer_end hook
 *
 * @hooked yummy_footer_end -  100
 * @hooked yummy_back_to_top -  110
 *
 */
do_action( 'yummy_footer_end' );
/**
 * yummy_page_end_action hook
 *
 * @hooked yummy_page_end -  10
 *
 */
do_action( 'yummy_page_end_action' ); 
?>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using a text editor with `multiple file search` search for `yummy_footer_start `. It may be used in your theme's functions.php

Comment: I would have to open up every files - thousands to do that, no? That is the point I thought of windows indexed search which I did and it came back with nothing.

Comment: that’s why I suggested multiple file search and I marked just the necessary part to search for. I recommend you download and install VS Code and open your theme as a folder inside VS Code. Its search will easily find the search string among all the files within your theme folder.

Comment: Thanks not sure how that differs from Windows indexed searching of all the files?